# Make SQLAlchemy use desired table in join

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a query that uses multiple outer joins and running into an issue where SQLAlchemy is picking the wrong table.

Here's my desired query -

```sql
SELECT 
    vocab_term.id,
    COALESCE(max(vocab_session_entry.question_level), 0) AS score
FROM 
    vocab_set
JOIN
    vocab_term
    on vocab_term.set_id = vocab_set.id
LEFT JOIN
    vocab_session
    on vocab_session.set_id = vocab_set.id
LEFT JOIN
    vocab_session_entry
    on vocab_session_entry.session_id = vocab_session.id and vocab_session_entry.term_id = vocab_term.id
WHERE 
    vocab_set.id = %(id_1)s
    AND vocab_session.user_id = %(user_id_1)s
GROUP BY
    vocab_set.id, vocab_term.id, vocab_session.user_id;
```

and here's my SQLAlchemy implementation:

```py
db.session.query(VocabTerm.id, coalesce(func.max(VocabSessionEntry.question_level)))
    .join(VocabTerm, VocabTerm.set_id==VocabSet.id)
    .join(VocabSession, VocabSession.set_id==VocabSet.id, isouter=True)
    .join(VocabSessionEntry, and_(VocabSessionEntry.session_id, VocabSessionEntry.term_id==VocabTerm.id), isouter=True)
    .filter(VocabSet.id==vocab_set_id)
    .filter(VocabSession.user_id==user_id)
    .group_by(VocabSet.id, VocabTerm.id, VocabSession.user_id)
    .all()
```

and here's what I'm ending up with (produced by SQLAlchemy:

```sql
SELECT
    vocab_term.id AS vocab_term_id,
    coalesce(max(vocab_session_entry.question_level)) AS score
FROM
    vocab_session_entry
JOIN
    vocab_term ON vocab_term.set_id = vocab_set.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    vocab_session
    ON vocab_session.set_id = vocab_set.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    vocab_session_entry
    ON vocab_session_entry.session_id AND vocab_session_entry.term_id = vocab_term.id
WHERE
    vocab_set.id = %(id_1)s
    AND vocab_session.user_id = %(user_id_1)s
GROUP BY
    vocab_set.id, vocab_term.id, vocab_session.user_id]
```

The only difference is SQLAlchemy is using vocab_session_entry rather than vocab_set as its FROM table. Is there any way that I can make SQLAlchemy use vocab_set as the from table?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs into this question - you can explicitly set the from clause using Query.select_from(). [Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_from)